# Devise - Register a user while I'm logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'd like to register a new user while I'm logged in, but the devise default dont allow this.

Someone know how I can change this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

devise is about authentication of users, even if it lets you to register *new* non-authenticated users.

if you want to add more users or manage them, it's better to create a dedicated controller, then implement an authorization system (using some gem like cancan or whatever you prefer).